# How to tell CMake to link executable against library?

Tags: c++, cmake

My source tree is

- CMakeLists.txt

  - Demo

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - source, headers.
  - Library

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - source, headers.

So Demo is the executable which is done with add_executable()
and Library is obviously the library. How can those 2 be linked together?

Because right now I am using target_link_libraries(Demo Library) but I am getting Error: LNK2019 which I think is caused by not linking successfully.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

edit: On root CMakeLists.txt those 2 are added as -> add_subdirectory(Library) add_subdirectory(Demo).

edit2:
  **Demo CMakeLists**

```
add_executable(Demo ${Headers}
                    ${Source})

target_link_libraries(Demo ${blahblah}
                           ${Library})
```

**Library CMakeLists**

```
add_library(Library blahblah.cpp
                    blahblah.h
                    foo.cpp
                    foo.h)
```

Comment: i have similar project structure and it works with no errors. can you show us your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Hi, i can't really but i will edit above to something close enough.

Comment: As you have `add_library(Library ...)`, you need to use exactly that name for link with: `target_link_libraries(Demo Library)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev What you said. Guess we raced to it

Comment: @Tsyvarev is correct.  Looks like you just need to remove the `${}` around `Library` in your Demo CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 3):

This is incorrect:

```
target_link_libraries(Demo ${blahblah}
                           ${Library})
```

What you are saying is to use the string variable called Library, which won't exist.

Use:

```
target_link_libraries(Demo ${blahblah}
                               Library)
```

so that CMake will know you are referencing the target "Library" and not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above, Library is a target name, not a variable. When you link it to your executable, use `target_link_libraries(Demo Library)` (no '${}' around 'Library').

Comment: @ur1234567 nothing. mascoj must have posted between when I opened the question and posted a response.